# recursion and closures in python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, recursion, closures

env python 3.8.2
I can't get the value var `return`

```
def a(x):
    def b():
        nonlocal x
        if x>2:
            print(x)
            return x
        x = x + 1
        b()
    return b

print(a(1)())
```

the result is

```
4
None
```

i want to return the value of x, but is't None, even though the value printed

Comment: I get 3 instead of 4

Comment: the result is 
3 
None

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Return `b()`. The first time you call b, it reaches `b()` but returns nothing, so your final return value is None.

```py
def a(x):
    def b():
        nonlocal x
        if x>2:
            print(x)
            return x
        x = x + 1
        return b()
    return b

print(a(1)())
> 3
> 3
```